# Copying and renaming files

Tags: copy, rename

I am trying to copy multiple files from separate folders and paste them in a new folder with new filenames.
Can anyone help me with the same?
For example: I have folder 1,2,3,4,5 and each one of them has filex.txt
I wish to take file.txt from each folder and rename it as 1filex, 2filex, 3filex, 4filex, 5filex and their new location to be folderabc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, do you have tried something to resolve by yourself?

Comment: You'll need a script or a C program to do this. Any experience in programming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be broken down into a few steps.

1. Make your destination directory if it doesn't exist
2. Copy the file named filex.txt from directory 1 to your destination
3. Repeat step 2 for directories 2, 3, 4, and 5.

You could do this in a 1 line script, but to make it easier to follow you can put it into a file named `script.sh` in the directory where you need to do your work.

```
#!/bin/bash

# A placeholder for our destination directory name
DESTDIR=folderabc

# Make your destination directory if it doesn't exist

if [ ! -d $DESTDIR ]; then
    mkdir $DESTDIR;
fi;


# repeat for directories 1-5
for d in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    # Copy file from computed source to computed destination file
    cp "$d/filex.txt" "$DESTDIR/${d}filex.txt"
done
```

When you start, your files will be like this (using `tree`).

```
user$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── filex.txt
├── 2
│   └── filex.txt
├── 3
│   └── filex.txt
├── 4
│   └── filex.txt
├── 5
│   └── filex.txt
└── script.sh
```

To execute your file, you can type `bash script.sh`. There are other things like permissions you might look into.

When you finish your files should look like this:

```
user$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── filex.txt
├── 2
│   └── filex.txt
├── 3
│   └── filex.txt
├── 4
│   └── filex.txt
├── 5
│   └── filex.txt
├── folderabc
│   ├── 1filex.txt
│   ├── 2filex.txt
│   ├── 3filex.txt
│   ├── 4filex.txt
│   └── 5filex.txt
└── script.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will try doing it this way.

Comment: Hello, step 2 in your solution suggests I make a folder. But I already have the existing folders labelled a_folder b_folder c_folder. And each folder has filex.txt. Now I want to move these filex.txt into folder abc. So acc to your script: cp "$d/filex.txt" "$DESTDIR/${d}filex.txt" my $d is a_folder, b_folder and so on right? But how would the loop recognize the various folders then?

Comment: In step 2, it would create the destination folder only if it wasn't there already. Your problem described copying files from folders named 1,2,3,4,5 to files named 1filex.txt. If you are changing from a_folder/filex.txt and copying to abcfolder/afilex you could change the script a little to accomodate that. Something like changing 1 2 3 4 5 to a b c d e, and cp "${d}_folder/filex"  "$DESTDIR/${d}filex.txt" should do it. Instead of using cp, try using echo to test what commands might be done by printing them to screen, and then removing echo once you are confident your script will work.

Answer (score 1):

For the case given in your question, a simple script like this will do:

```
for d in {1..5}; do echo cp "$d/filex.txt" "folderabc/${d}filex"; done
```

The destination directory `folderabc` must exist - if it doesn't, then create it first with `mkdir folderabc`.

Remove the `echo` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was trying a similar command using awk which did not work but I will try this too.